# mongodb set feature compatibility to 3.4 fail

Tags: mongodb

I want to enable the features of my Mongodb 3.4 after upgrading.
I have sharded cluster enviroment
And after I ran the commands:

```
use admin
db.adminCommand ({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4"})
```

In mongos instance
I got the following output:

> {"ok": 1}

But when I try to check with it succeeded with command:

```
db.adminCommand ({getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1})
```

I get the following output:

> {"ok": 0, "errmsg": "no option found to get"}

And when I check in ops manager I see that the command did not work

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: That said, there should be no reason to actually do this unless you really want to deliberately disable feature compatibility on a MongoDB 3.6 node in preparation for "downgrade" to a previous version. If you think you are doing this for any other reason, then it's actually the wrong reason. Only do this if you intend to replace the binaries completely. Where the "downgrade" is of course a DBA action. Go and discuss it on the correct site please.